# Change button style on jQuery slide toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a callback function on my project.

Can i change the button style?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".slide-toggle").click(function(){
            $(".box").animate({
                width: "toggle"
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
     <button type="button" class="slide-toggle">Callback</button>
     <div class="box">
         <div class="box-inner">Lorem</div>
     </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: change what?of what?into what? :)

Comment: Change color, font and background ))

Comment: why not add a class on the element and toggle the class to change the style

Comment: check this simple sample https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/2hnyq2fn/

Comment: guradio tnx, but i'm need change style of button Callback... (

Comment: @MaksimMedvedev check this one https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/2hnyq2fn/1/

Comment: @MaksimMedvedev glad it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery function toggleClass to add/remove class to an element. This way your code is clean and you can use same animations everywhere in your code and can modify them easily.

**See the example below.** 
In current example we add `skin` class to box element on button click. You can modify `skin` class however you like. I also added the `box-transition` class to make the animating effect, you can also edit how you would like, I recommend checking [this](https://matthewlein.com/ceaser/).

```js
$(function(){

  $('.slide-toggle').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.box').toggleClass('skin');
  });

});
```

```css
.box{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #f34;
}

.box-transition{
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
}

.skin{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.active{
  background: #ccc;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="slide-toggle">Callback</button>
<div class="box box-transition">
  <div class="box-inner">Lorem</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slide-toggle").click(function(){
        $(".box").animate({
            width: "toggle",
            color: '#f00',
            background: '#00f'
        });
    });
});
```

or as they mentioned in the comments us a class

```
<style>
    .your_class {
        color: #f00;
        background: #00f;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".slide-toggle").click(function(){
            $(".box").animate({
                width: "toggle"
            }).toggleClass('your_class');
        });
    });
</script>
```

(and next time use the right tags)